# document.getElementById('idname').value just returns [object HTMLInputElement] when printed

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, tampermonkey

So I'm using a Tamper-monkey script that will scrape a singular page for text, return the value of 3 buttons on the page (pick_0, pick _1, and pick_2) and print them in a box lower on the page. It's more complicated than that but honestly I'm just trying to get it to read the stupid values first.

So yeah what's killing me is that it hasn't been grabbing the values correctly, and I don't know if it's the way it's getting the element, or the way it's getting the page.

Also EVERY single time I find an answer on any site, they specify that ".value" should be added to fix it, which it is. So I'm at a dead end, thus this question being posted.

A friend gave me the page scraping code, which is what I'm worrying might not be working. However I've tried a few others on Stack Overflow, to no avail.
Note: The TamperMonkey script is set to only run on the specific page I need to scrape anyways, thus him not really specifying it in the code.

```
function getLink(url) {
    return $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            url:  url,
        });     
}
```

My variables:

```
function inputs() {
    var pick_0b = document.getElementById('pick_0').value;
    var pick_1b = document.getElementById('pick_1').value;
    var pick_2b = document.getElementById('pick_2').value;
}
```

The printing part of it is working fine, it worked printing a dummy variable with similar syntax. But yeah, every time I try to print out one of these guys, I just either get one of these two.

```
undefined

[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Help?
Edit: HTML for the buttons themselves is thus:

```
<tr><td class="centered"><input type="submit" name="pick_0" value="longass string of randomized text here"  class="button" id="pick_0" /></td></tr>
<tr><td class="centered"><input type="submit" name="pick_1" value="longass string of secondary random text here"  class="button" id="pick_1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td class="centered"><input type="submit" name="pick_2" value="longass third string of random text here"  class="button" id="pick_2" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: try either `.innerHtml` or `.innerText` instead of `.value`.

Comment: How is `getLink` connected to to `inputs`?

Comment: .innetHtml and .innerText didn't work, though thank you for the response. And they aren't really, they're just two functions set to go after one another. However what confuses me is that his old code (in which that's how it's set up, two functions just going in order) in which he gave me this function, it worked flawlessly. Except his values he was grabbing were numbers, not strings of text from a button.

Comment: have you the html markup for the 'pick_0' /etc?

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: You know the inputs are submits.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inputs() {
    var pick_0b = document.getElementsByName('pick_0');
    var pick_1b = document.getElementsByName('pick_1');
    var pick_2b = document.getElementsByName('pick_2');
}
```

To access:

```
alert(pick_0b[0].value);
```

Do either of these work?

```
function inputs() {
    var pick_0b = document.getElementsByName('pick_0');
    var pick_1b = document.getElementsByName('pick_1');
    var pick_2b = document.getElementsByName('pick_2');

    alert(pick_0b[0].value);
}
```

or

```
var pick_0b = ""
var pick_1b = ""
var pick_2b = ""

function inputs() {
    document.getElementsByName('pick_0');
    document.getElementsByName('pick_1');
    document.getElementsByName('pick_2');
}

alert(pick_0b[0].value);
```

Edit: You've probably fixed this by now, but if not...

I had another look at your pastebin file... if tampermonkey is as fussy as greasemonkey you might have a problem with your metadata block - try making the second column all line up.

Yours:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Result Reader
// @namespace  tarakore.com
// @version    1.0
// @description  Stupid description goes here.
// @match      http://www.(removedurl).com/game/* //Url removed because the site in question wouldn't want attention from this post.
// @copyright  2014+ Tarakore/Katiki
// @grant   GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

Possibly fixed:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Result Reader
// @namespace    tarakore.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  Stupid description goes here.
// @match        http://www.(removedurl).com/game/* 
// @copyright    2014+ Tarakore/Katiki
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

Also, you might try removing the copyright line for the heck of it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried yours, returned same error so I had it go to console instead, received the error `ReferenceError: pick_0b is not defined` followed by a large amount of... something. [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZbI06ke.png). Same error happened when using console on all other methods I used from the other commenters.

Comment: @Katiki I don't think you're using greasemonkey, lol...  Well that code outside a function works fine in greasemonkey.  I think I need to see the rest of your code... it looks like you're setting those variables inside the function and it's not passing the values...

Comment: @Katiki Added tests to my answer

Comment: It's tampermonkey not greasemonkey, which is, eh. I dunno, I've never tried using it before. It says it should work the same as firefox's greasemonkey extension but chrome is picky. I'll try the tests and see what happens.

Comment: First one returned nothing whatsoever (either as alert or console.log), second one returned same error in chrome's console as before. Alerts don't seem to work in tampermonkey.

Comment: @Katiki  grrr... any chance you can post or link to the whole script?  I think we need to see the rest of it... And is it possible for you to test it in greasemonkey/firefox to see if you get the same errors?  I would install tampermonkey myself, but I really don't want to download it on dialup...

Comment: Yeah sure but the code in the post pretty much is the whole script so far. Of course it was supposed to be more but due to the issues with the variables I haven't gone much further. Unless the issue is with the page get (which I've been thinking it probably is) or with the tampermonkey/greasemonkey header. (Which is also probably is because I'm stupid and dyslexic.) [Pastebin Here](http://pastebin.com/S24mdTyD)

Comment: @Katiki I still can't understand jquery... I see 2 possible issues... it would help if I could test on the actual site, but... If you're getting the info with the ajax request you have to parse the results instead of using 'document' because 'document' runs on the currently open page... if your goal is to get links from those buttons and do something with them then you're doing it right.  But, if those buttons load later in the page (which is why I wish I could test on the actual site), you can either wrap it in a button so you can run it after the buttons are loaded, or use waitForKeyElements

Comment: @Katiki I added a possibility about the metadata block if you are still looking for a solution